# App con Open weathermap, funciona en browser, en móvil no

Tags: ionic3

Ionic 3.2. tengo una llamada a Openweathermap, con ionic serve funciona correctamente en el browser (Chrome), pero cuando hago el build, la apk en el móvil no trae datos, y no sé cómo debuguearla allí. Les agradeceré si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias! :-)

Provider:

```
getClima() {
return this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=' + this.latitud + '&lon=' + this.longitud + '&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&units=metric');}
```

Código:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
this.clima.getClima()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.clima_get = data['city'];
      this.forecast_get = data['list'];    ............
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo este ejemplo que me va perfecto en el móvil:

```
// Get weather information from API
Api_weather() {
    this.idioma  = localStorage.getItem('idioma');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.lat}&lon=${this.lon}&appid=${this.apiKey}&lang=${this.idioma}&units=metric`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
        });
     }); }

// Format weather information to show
this.weatherData.Api_weather(this.coordinates).then((response)=>{       
   this.weather  = response;
   console.log('====| Current Weather: ', this.weather);
});
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por responder! he detectado cual es el problema real. Cuando tengo activado en mi móvil el icono de geolocalización, me puedo geolocalizar y por lo tanto obtener datos de clima. 

Pero....el problema es obtener antes latitud y longitud. Si apago la geoloc..., no funciona. 


Quiero ser independiente de activar o no la geoloc. en mi móvil. ESTO ES POSIBLE ?

Comment: constructor(public geolocation: Geolocation, public global: GlobalProvider, public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.global.latitude = resp.coords.latitude
      this.global.longitude = resp.coords.longitude
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert('Error getting location ' + error);
    });
    }